# I have a bitcoin miner

Tags: mining-hardware

I have a bitcoin miner I purchased 5 months ago from B and C Tech Solutions. I want to sale my server but I don't know what type it is? The salesman said it is custom made and wouldn't give me any specs on it. How can I identify this server with no outward tags? [image]

Comment: so, are you thinking we're mind readers?  Give us something to go on.  Perhaps a photograph of the unit.  Or something, anything really.

Comment: There's no stickers

Comment: I'll give you $50 for it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually devices have a sticker on the back or bottom. It tells you serial number, make and product number. You can also try to make a clear picture of the device and run it through Google reverse image search.